# How to find missed call and not answered call in android

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

when somebody called us for onetime and disconnects comes under missed call.
sometimes we disconnect the call comes under not answered call.
how to vary and find missed call and not answered through programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) should give you a start as to how they are classified.

Comment: I want to find the last call is rejected or missed call in Broadcast receiver class. I tried to read call logs in broadcast receiver but it is not able to read the last call . It shows cursor count 0 when i tried to read call logs.

Comment: I feel like the answer lies in understanding the __IS_READ__ attribute.  If a call __IS_READ__ and has __MISSED_TYPE__ tied to it, then the call was likely ignored.  If you have to go to before API 14, try adapting the __NEW__ attribute instead.

Comment: i tried to read calllogs from class that extends service but cursor is not able to read last call from calllogs.calls